# Select only records with last date

Tags: sql, date

I executed this query :

```
SELECT
    bookings.id
    , bookings.confirmed_at
    , bookings.disputed
    , bookings.disputed_at
    , bookings.no_show_blocked_until
    , bookings.user_id
    , bookings.refunded
    , bookings.refunded_at
    , invoices.id AS invoice_id
    , invoices.state
    , invoices.currency_to_eur
    , lessons.time
FROM
    bookings
    LEFT JOIN invoice_lines
        ON invoice_lines.booking_id = bookings.id
    LEFT JOIN invoices
        ON invoices.id = invoice_lines.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN lesson_bookings
        ON lesson_bookings.booking_id = bookings.id
    LEFT JOIN lessons
        ON lessons.id = lesson_bookings.lesson_id
```

My problem is that the partition I get shows many records with same booking_id and invoice_id, but different dates from the lessons time column. For records having the same booking id and invoice id, I'd like to get only the ones with last date. How can I do please ?

example :

booking_id        invoice_id              date

123                   325              01/01/2020
123                   325              01/02/2020
123                   200              01/05/2020
123                   300              01/05/2020
200                   600              07/08/2020

What I want to get is :

123                   325             01/02/2020
123                   200             01/05/2020
123                   300             01/05/2020
200                   600             07/08/2020

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output in text

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and date functions are quite vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Tag added ! I'm working with Postgresql actually

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE lessons.time = 
    (SELECT MAX(l.time) 
    FROM lessons l 
    WHERE l.id = lessons.id)
```

Comment: I added this code but still showing records having same booking_id/invoice_id with different date values